# How do I reset my root password for MySQL on Mac OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, mac, unix, mysql

I downloaded and installed mysql-5.7.16-osx10.11-x86_64.dmg and I am running MySQL with Pref Pane: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/osx-installation-prefpane.html

And I have attempted to follow the instructions on this page (Section B.5.3.2.2 Resetting the Root Password: Unix and Unix-Like Systems)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Supposedly, completing steps 1 to 5 running `shell> mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &` will reset my root password but it doesn't do anything. I've also attempted step 6 to no avail.

Comment: Yes. I stopped MySQL server from Pref Pane and then performed steps 3 to 5, then I restarted MySQL server from Pref Pane before trying my new password, but it does not work.

Comment: @ITSolutions did the steps work for you?

Comment: just to ensure,  the text file you created wasn't really named:  '/home/me/mysql-init'  was it?

Comment: It was not. It was created in my home direction `~/mysql-init` and the command I used was `mysqld_safe --init-file=~/mysql-init &`

Comment: What happens if you run the `cat /mysql-data-directory/host_name.pid` command (without the kill and backticks, just on its own)?  If you get some number, then mysql is still running.  Also, like my last question, that wasn't the actual text you used inside the `kill` command, was it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I ran `mysqld_safe --init-file=~/mysql-init &`, `mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/Zhous-MacBook-Pro.local.err'` was printed to the console.

Tailing the error log, I found that it could not find mysql-init because it does not recognize `~` as home. I changed the path to `/users/Zhou/mysql-init` and it worked like a charm.